Magento 2 add product to existing order problem (tax summary)
i have a module that ads product to existing order but the problem is that when adding product to order tax summary is not updating and I see table sales_order_tax and sales_order_tax_item are not populated with new product info on tax.
Code that adds products to order:
    protected function _addProductToOrder($product, $order)
    {
        $orderItem = $this->orderFactory->create()->getItemsCollection()->getNewEmptyItem();
        $orderItem->setProduct($product);
        $orderItem->setQtyOrdered(1);
        
        // Set additional product information
        $orderItem->setName($product->getName());
        $orderItem->setSku($product->getSku());
        $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();
        $orderItem->setStoreId($storeId);
        $orderItem->setProductId($product->getId());
        $orderItem->setWeight($product->getWeight());
        $orderItem->setIsVirtual(0);
    
        // Set custom price (promo or final)
        $promoPrice = $product->getPromoPrice();
        $priceInclTax = $promoPrice ? $promoPrice : $product->getFinalPrice();
    
        // Get the tax class ID and customer ID
        $taxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
    
        // Calculate the tax rate
        $taxRate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($taxClassId, $customerId, $storeId);
    
        // Price excluding tax
        $priceExclTax = $priceInclTax / (1 + ($taxRate / 100));
        $taxAmount = $priceInclTax - $priceExclTax;
    
        // Set item prices and tax information
        //$orderItem->setBaseCost($priceExclTax); // Base cost without tax
        $orderItem->setPrice($priceExclTax);
        $orderItem->setPriceInclTax($priceInclTax);
        $orderItem->setBasePrice($priceExclTax);  // Base price excluding tax
        $orderItem->setBasePriceInclTax($priceInclTax); // Base price including tax
        $orderItem->setOriginalPrice($priceInclTax); // Original price excl tax
        $orderItem->setBaseOriginalPrice($priceExclTax); // Base original price excl tax

        // Set tax information
        $orderItem->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
        $orderItem->setTaxPercent($taxRate);
        $orderItem->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount);

        // Set row totals
        $orderItem->setRowTotal($priceExclTax);
        $orderItem->setBaseRowTotal($priceExclTax);
        $orderItem->setRowTotalInclTax($priceInclTax);
        $orderItem->setBaseRowTotalInclTax($priceInclTax);
    
        // Add the item to the order
        $order->addItem($orderItem);
        $orderItem->setOrder($order);
        $orderItem->save();
        $order->save();
        
        return $orderItem;
    }


After that I am alos updating order totals like this:
        $order->setSubtotal($newSubtotal);
        $order->setBaseSubtotal($newSubtotal);
        $order->setSubtotalInclTax($newSubtotal + $newTaxAmount);
        $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($newSubtotal + $newTaxAmount);
        $order->setTaxAmount($newTaxAmount + $shippingTaxAmount);
        $order->setBaseTaxAmount($newTaxAmount + $baseShippingTaxAmount);
    
        // Calculate new grand total with the updated values
        $order->setGrandTotal($newSubtotal + $newTaxAmount + $shippingAmount + $shippingTaxAmount);
        $order->setBaseGrandTotal($newSubtotal + $newTaxAmount + $baseShippingAmount + $baseShippingTaxAmount);
        $order->setTotalItemCount($count);
        $order->setTotalQtyOrdered($count);
        // Save the updated order
        $order->save();

What is the reason? what am I missing?
Also if I want to edit order newly added products are not on the product list (ony items that were on when order was created).


i think you might be missing the call to a magento 2 method called collectTotals(); it's called quite often and it's updating all the data.

CollectTotals is only for quote as I know?

In my experience, adding a product to an order after it’s already been placed is not the best idea. I’d recommend finding a "cancel and replace" module instead. Even though that might not be your first choice, it ensures that all invoices, shipments, and credit memos are handled in line with Magento’s total calculations and processes.
It's similar to deleting an entity — I’ve been working with Magento since version 1, and deleting has never been best practice. I always prefer to deactivate, archive, cancel, issue a credit memo, or even anonymize if needed, rather than lose or alter data. It saves you from a lot of headaches down the line.
